# How to find total distance traveled using multiple latitude and longitude using google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i have multiple latitude,longitude (count of 415) in database that cover nearly 280 km  now i need to know based on latitude,longitude distance.

My sample API code:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins=12.9869,79.9785&destinations=12.9869,79.9785|12.9866,79.9781|12.9844,79.9747|12.9825,79.9703|12.9819,79.969|12.9819,79.969|12.9809,79.9669|12.9788,79.9626|12.9761,79.9586|12.9727,79.9561|12.968,79.954|12.9642,79.9502|12.9634,79.9478|12.9632,79.9473|12.9631,79.9469|12.9629,79.9465|12.9629,79.9464|12.9628,79.946|12.9606,79.9444|12.9573,79.9437|12.9559,79.9422|12.9554,79.9402|12.955,79.9368|12.9542,79.9338|12.9536,79.9331|12.9512,79.9296|12.9487,79.9262|12.9452,79.9227|12.9424,79.9191|12.9397,79.9157|12.9364,79.9118|12.9334,79.9081|12.9333,79.9051|12.9333,79.9026|12.932,79.8988|12.9291,79.8931|&key=XXXX"
```

but i gives me distance for each latitude,longitude difference i need only total distance covered by all latitude,longitude.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the last element is the total distance/duration. Have a look at the durations and distances...they are increasing from element to element:

```
<element>
  <status>OK</status>
  <duration>
    <value>807</value>
    <text>13 Minuten</text>
  </duration>
  <distance>
    <value>11166</value>
    <text>6,9 Meile/n</text>
  </distance>
</element>

//Last element:
<element>
  <status>OK</status>
  <duration> //Total duration
    <value>849</value>
    <text>14 Minuten</text>
  </duration>
  <distance> //Total distance
    <value>11867</value>
    <text>7,4 Meile/n</text>
  </distance>
</element>
```

So from the one element to the other it takes 1 minute and 0,5 miles. The last element shows the total distance and duration (in your case 14 minutes and 7,4 miles).